# SQL Server error 19456 when adding the listener

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups, clustering, high-availability, listener

I have three replica same subnet both has a Private and public network. I was able to create the cluster and create the availability group . When I try to add the listener I get the below error

> None of the IP addresses configured for the availability group
>   listener can be hosted by the server 'Cluster'. Either configure a
>   public cluster network on which one of the specified IP addresses can
>   be hosted, or add another listener IP address which can be hosted on a
>   public cluster network for this server.

This kind of error comes when there are two subnets and only one was included in the listener . Under the cluster validation there is also a warning that RegisterAllProvidersIP  should be 0 instead of 1. I am clueless as this is in the same data center. I can create the AG and listener when I exclude the 'Cluster' but when I include the server 'Cluster' I get the above error.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might helpful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80671/alwayson-availability-group-listener-in-a-multi-subnet-cluster

Comment: Thanks I went through those but i have the same subnet and this error should not happen with same subnets

Comment: Your subnet definitions are incorrect, somewhere. Please update the question with the output from each cluster network interface (IPv4 only) ip address and subnet mask or CIDR value and the values you're setting the listener to. Without those pieces of information it is impossible to tell.